# Ckeditor in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate Ckeditor (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) into my Rails 3.0 application. The documentation states to use version **3.6.3** of the gem for Rails 3.0 and below.  I successfully install the gem and run the generator :

```
rails generate ckeditor:install
```

I get the following error:

```
fetching rails.js  
/home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
    from /home/alexs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_o
```

Are there are any workarounds/solutions to this issue?

Comment: Upgrade your Ruby version to at least `1.9.3-p194`. That release included some RubyGems security fixes related to secure connections, and RubyGems no longer allows https => http redirects, which could be the source of the problem. More info [here](http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).

Comment: Yeah, that's would be the long-run solution, for now I've gotta hack my way through 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following workaround

Locate **open-uri.rb** in the Ruby installation.

Temporarily change

```
http.verify_mode = options[:ssl_verify_mode] || OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

To

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Run the generator, then change it back.